# Convertir tipo de datos en un store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

tengo el siguiente problema en mi store procedure, con el casteo de datos

PRIMERO
 El diseño de mi tabla, la columna tratada es MontoNeto de tipo DECIMAL
 Mi Variable es @limite int = 0

Mi objetivo es traer todos los datos en el rango del 5% de acuerdo a un valor 
 establecido

```
if @limite is not null
                begin
                    if @aux = 1
                        begin
                            set @consulta = @consulta + ' and MontoNeto >= ' + CAST ( @limite as decimal (18,2)) + ' - ( ' + CAST ( @limite as decimal (18,2)) + ' * .05 ) '
                            set @consulta = @consulta + ' and MontoNeto <= ' + CAST ( @limite as decimal (18,2)) 
                        end
                    else
                        begin
                            set @aux = 1
                            set @consulta = @consulta + ' where MontoNeto >= ' + CAST ( @limite as decimal (18,2)) + ' - ( ' + CAST ( @limite as decimal (18,2)) + ' * .05 ) '
                            set @consulta = @consulta + ' and MontoNeto <=  ' + CAST ( @limite as decimal (18,2)) 
                        end
                end
```

Comment: Es que estás concatenando una cadena, no puedes "castear" la variables a un numérico, debes hacerlo a un `VARCHAR`.

Comment: me tira este error:  Error de desbordamiento aritmético al convertir varchar al tipo de datos numeric

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un anti-patrón de desarrollo en tu código. Nunca debes crear cadenas en base a parámetros. Siempre tienes que parametrizar tus consultas, de tal modo que el código quedaría algo así.

```
if @limite is not null
begin
    if @aux = 1
        begin
            set @consulta = @consulta + ' and MontoNeto >= @limite - ( @limite * .05 ) ' + CHAR(10)
            set @consulta = @consulta + ' and MontoNeto <= @limite '
        end
    else
        begin
            set @aux = 1
            set @consulta = @consulta + ' WHERE MontoNeto >= @limite - ( @limite * .05 ) ' + CHAR(10)
            set @consulta = @consulta + ' and MontoNeto <= @limite '
        end
end
```

Y al llamarlo utilizas el procedimiento especial `sp_executesql`

```
EXEC sp_executesql @consulta, N'@limite decimal (18,2)', @limite = @limite;
```

Recuerda que @consulta debe ser NVARCHAR y puedes asignarle una longitud de MAX.

NOTA: También puedes simplificar tu código un poco de esta forma.

```
and MontoNeto >= @limite * .95
```